# Fetch different columns from different google sheets using Query

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am running into issues with a fairly simple QUERY statement in Google Spreadsheets. The goal is to get data (unique cells/values) from different sheets (same file). The example shows that I am using the cell reference from two sheets.

```
=QUERY({TeamScaled!I:I,TeamRx!M:M, TeamLeadScaled!I:I, TeamLeadScaled!M:M},)
```

**The result:** data gets distributed in 4 (E,F, G, H) columns and not 2 (E & F). How can I bring everything to E and F? I tried separating sheets by a semi-column but that wipes off the data.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtCPS.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Instead of adding sample data as image, add it as text. Use markdown to format it as table. It's not clear what you mean by "sem-column" (did you tried to say semi-colon `;`)?. What is the spreadsheet locale / country or your spreadsheet?

Comment: If you are looking to get unique values use UNIQUE instead of QUERY.